# Unable to get the 3rd party digital signature of a dll file

Tags: c#, digital-signature

I am using the following code to validate the signature of a specific dll:

```
 var runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
        {
            runspace.Open();
            using (var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
            {
                pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptCommand);
                var results = pipeline.Invoke();
                runspace.Close();

                var signature = results[0].BaseObject as Signature;
                if (signature.Status != SignatureStatus.NotSigned)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(signature.StatusMessage);
                }

            }
        }
```

In the properties of the dll, I can see the signatures by Microsoft (sha256) and third party (sha1). The code doesn't help check the 3rd party signature.
How should I do it?